# ThreadPool QueueUserWorkItem with list

Tags: c#, multithreading, threadpool

I would like to use the QueueUserWorkItem from the ThreadPool. When I use the following code everything works well.

```
private int ThreadCountSemaphore = 0;
private void (...) {

var reportingDataList = new List<LBReportingData>();
ThreadCountSemaphore = reportingDataList.Count;
using (var autoResetEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false)) {
   ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((o) => this.FillReportingData(settings, reportingDataList[0], autoResetEvent));
   ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((o) => this.FillReportingData(settings, reportingDataList[1], autoResetEvent));
   ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((o) => this.FillReportingData(settings, reportingDataList[2], autoResetEvent));
}
}

private void FillReportingData(...) {
if (Interlocked.Decrement(ref this.ThreadCountSemaphore) == 0) {
                waitHandle.Set();
                }
}
```

But when I use a list instead the single method calls, then my program crash without an exception.

```
private void (...) {

var reportingDataList = new List<LBReportingData>();
ThreadCountSemaphore = reportingDataList.Count;
using (var autoResetEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false)) {
   ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((o) => this.FillReportingData(settings, reportingDataList[i], autoResetEvent));
}
}
```

What do i wrong? What should I change?

**Update**

Sorry, I've made a fault in the code. I use .NET 2.0 with VS2010.
Here's the complete code:

```
private int ThreadCountSemaphore = 0;

        private IList<LBReportingData> LoadReportsForBatch() {
            var reportingDataList = new List<LBReportingData>();
            var settings = OnNeedEntitySettings();

            if (settings.Settings.ReportDefinition != null) {
                var definitionList = new List<ReportDefinitionen> { ReportDefinitionen.OrgStatus, ReportDefinitionen.Mittelwerte, ReportDefinitionen.Verteilungsstatistik };
                using (var autoResetEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false)) {
                    foreach (var reportDefinition in definitionList) {
                        foreach (DataRow row in settings.Settings.ReportDefinition.Select("AuswertungsTyp = " + (int)reportDefinition)) {
                            reportingDataList.Add(new LBReportingData { SourceData = row, ReportType = reportDefinition });
                        }
                    }

                    ThreadCountSemaphore = reportingDataList.Count;

                    foreach(var reportingDataItem in reportingDataList) {                                       
                        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((o) => this.FillReportingData(settings, reportingDataItem, autoResetEvent));
                    }
                    autoResetEvent.WaitOne();
                }
            }
            return reportingDataList;
        }

private void FillReportingData(IEntitySettings<DSLBUReportDefinition> settings, LBReportingData reportingData, AutoResetEvent waitHandle){

            DoSomeWork();
            if (Interlocked.Decrement(ref this.ThreadCountSemaphore) == 0) {
                waitHandle.Set();
            }
        }
```

Thanks

Comment: Very unclear, where is the value of "i" supposed to come from?

Comment: If this is C#, the ellipsis is not an allowed parameter. Therefore, in order to better troubleshoot this issue, we'll need to know the parameter types you've declared for `FillReportingData`. Also, in example 2, you're still only passing a single `LBReportingData` object, not the entire list.

Answer (score 2):

You are disposing the `WaitHandle` immediately after queueing the work items. There is race between the call to `Dispose` in the main thread and `Set` in the worker thread. There may be other problems, but it is difficult to guess because the code is incomplete.

Here is how the pattern is suppose to work.

```
using (var finished = new CountdownEvent(1))
{
  foreach (var item in reportingDataList)
  {  
     var captured = item;
     finished.AddCount(); 
     ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(
       (state) =>
       {
         try
         {
           DoSomeWork(captured); // FillReportingData?
         }
         finally
         {
           finished.Signal();
         }
       }, null);
  } 
  finished.Signal();
  finished.Wait();
}
```

The code uses the [CountdownEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.countdownevent.aspx) class. It is available in .NET 4.0 or as part of the [Reactive Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/ee794896.aspx) download.

Comment: +1 The disposing of the AutoResetEvent was the first red flag I seen, however, without the full code it is difficult to pinpoint it exactly, but I would be adamant that this is part of the overall problem.

Answer (score 0):

As Hans pointed out, it is not clear where "i" is coming from. But also I can see your disposing block going out and disposed because you are not using WaitOne on it (or you have not copied that part of code).

Also I would prefer to use WaitAll and not using interlocked.

Comment: `WaitAll` in this particular scenario would be fine, however, it does have it's limitations at higher volumes.