# IIS 8.5 single worker process vs Web Garden performance

Tags: asp.net, multithreading, performance, iis

I have simple ASP.NET application which just resizes images with [ImageResizer](https://imageresizing.net) and does nothing else. For testing purposes I disabled disk caching, so images are resized on every request.

When I test performance of the app with JMeter I get the following average response times:

- single worker process, 1 concurrent clients: ~200ms
- single worker process, 10 concurrent clients: ~1200ms
- 4 worker processes, 10 concurrent clients: ~300ms

As you can see, when I run single worker process and 10 concurrent clients, response time increases dramatically despite of available hardware resources: CPU usage during performance test is ~30%, memory usage is ~150MB.

As discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5583470/does-a-webapplication-run-faster-when-maximum-worker-processes-is-more-than-one/5583899),

> Web gardens was designed for one single reason – Offering applications
>   that are not CPU-bound but execute long running requests the ability
>   to scale and not use up all threads available in the worker process.

This not seems as my case.

I don't understand why I get such result. What I expect is that even single worker process would provide acceptable response time until it reaches resources limits. And 10 concurrent clients are definitely not a heavy load. Can somebody explain to me, where am I wrong?

My configuration:

- Windows Server 2012 R2
- IIS 8.5 with all default settings (except MaxWorkerThreads)
- quad-core i3 3.4GHz CPU
- 16 GB RAM

My application is just empty ASP.NET MVC application with ImageResizer, added as in [this instruction](https://imageresizing.net/docs/v4/install) (option 3 - Manual Installation) and with DiskCache plugin disabled in Web.config

Comment: Just based on those numbers you provided, and without knowing anything about ImageResizer, it looks like ImageResizer is running resize operations in a single thread, maybe the STA? This (speculation) might be the case if it was based on a COM component which didn't support multiple threads.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found an answer thanks to @Ben's comment.

The problem is ImageResizer is based on GDI+ (as stated on [it's site](https://imageresizing.net)), which contains locks inside (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3719748/parallelizing-gdi-image-resizing-net) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18298525/multithreading-system-windows-graphics) posts for details). This is why it works so slowly in single process.

After finding the cause of problem I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3747577/775232). Referencing WPF assemblies from ASP.NET application is, probably, not a best idea, but it's ok for testing purposes.

Now I get the following results when I perform the same performance testing as in question:

- single worker process, 1 concurrent client: ~90ms
- single worker process, 10 concurrent clients: ~120ms
- single worker process, 40 concurrent clients: ~190ms
- single worker process, 60 concurrent clients: ~400ms
- single worker process, 80 concurrent clients: ~630ms

As you can see, now application works much faster. Also it utilizes almost all available CPU resources under high load, as I expected initially.

> So, if you process images in your ASP.NET application:
>
> - don't use GDI+ based solution, if you can
> - if you have to use GDI+, increase MaxWorkerProcesses in applicaion pool's settings

Comment: So what about two+ worker processes with the new code?

Comment: As far as I remember, there wasn't any difference between single and multiple worker processes with the new code: in both cases application has been scaling up without problems until reaching hardware resources limits.