# Why no speed gains when scaling images with Parallel.For?

Tags: c#, performance, parallel-processing

I am unable to get any speed gains when scaling several Bitmap in parallel.

Please review the following code that demonstrate the issue:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Bitmap[] images = Enumerable.Range(0, 8).Select(_ => new Bitmap(6000, 4000, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb)).ToArray();
        Bitmap[] scaledImages = Enumerable.Range(0, 8).Select(_ => new Bitmap(600, 400, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb)).ToArray();

        // Sequential image scaling:
        Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopwatch.Start();
        for(int i = 0; i < images.Length; i++)
        {
            ImageScaler(images[i], scaledImages[i]);
        }
        stopwatch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine($"Sequential scaling: {images.Length} images in {stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms.");

        // Parallel image scaling:
        stopwatch.Restart();
        Parallel.For(0, images.Length, i => ImageScaler(images[i], scaledImages[i]));
        stopwatch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine($"Parallel scaling: {images.Length} images in {stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms.");

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static void ImageScaler(Bitmap source, Bitmap destination)
    {
        using(Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(destination))
        {
            g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            g.DrawImage(source, 0, 0, destination.Width, destination.Height);
        }
    }
}
```

I get the following results on my system (a recent quad-core i7):

```
Sequential scaling: 8 images in 1774 ms.
Parallel scaling: 8 images in 1792 ms.
```

This is an unexpected result for two reasons:

- The images are fairly large (24 megapixel). The overhead of starting multiple threads should not have a significant impact.
- Image scaling is definitely a CPU bound operation.

To verify that, I replaced `ImageScaler()` in the code above by the following basic image scaling algorithm:

```
private static unsafe void NaiveImageScaler(Bitmap src, Bitmap dst)
{
    BitmapData srcBd = src.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, src.Width, src.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
    BitmapData dstBd = dst.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, dst.Width, dst.Height), ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
    unsafe
    {
        byte* srcBgr = (byte*)srcBd.Scan0.ToPointer();
        byte* dstBgr = (byte*)dstBd.Scan0.ToPointer();
        for(int yd=0; yd<dst.Height; yd++)
        {
            for(int xd = 0; xd < dst.Width; xd++)
            {
                int bSum = 0, gSum = 0, rSum = 0;
                for(int ys = 10*yd; ys < 10*yd+10; ys++)
                {
                    for(int xs = 10*xd; xs < 10*xd+10; xs++)
                    {
                        bSum += srcBgr[ys * srcBd.Stride + 3 * xs];
                        gSum += srcBgr[ys * srcBd.Stride + 3 * xs + 1];
                        rSum += srcBgr[ys * srcBd.Stride + 3 * xs + 2];
                    }
                }
                dstBgr[yd * dstBd.Stride + 3 * xd] = (Byte)(bSum / 100);
                dstBgr[yd * dstBd.Stride + 3 * xd + 1] = (Byte)(bSum / 100);
                dstBgr[yd * dstBd.Stride + 3 * xd + 2] = (Byte)(bSum / 100);
            }
        }
    }
    dst.UnlockBits(dstBd);
    src.UnlockBits(srcBd);
}
```

With this code, I get the following results:

```
Sequential scaling: 8 images in 660 ms.
Parallel scaling: 8 images in 184 ms.
```

The parallel implementation is now 3.6 time faster than the sequential one.

Why the discrepancy between the two approach that accomplish essentially the same work? Is there a limitation in System.Drawing that prevents running parallel code?

**Comments about the "Marked as duplicate":**

I do not think that [Multithreading System.Windows.Graphics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18298525/multithreading-system-windows-graphics) is an exact duplicate. The referred question is about drawing, this one is about image scaling. The subjects are related but are not exactly the same.

I do agree that the underlying explanation (critical regions in GDI) applies to the two questions.

I believe that I have found a closer duplicate to my own question(!) :
[Parallelizing GDI+ Image Resizing .net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3719748/parallelizing-gdi-image-resizing-net)

Comment: This migh interest you (while not directly being an answer to your question): [Rendering fast with GDI+ - What to do and what not to do!](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/66909/Rendering-fast-with-GDI-What-to-do-and-what-not-to)

Comment: This SO thread is probably the answer you are looking for: [Multithreading System.Windows.Graphics](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18298525/880990).